# How can I create a new column with values 1/0, where the value in the new column is 1 only if values in two other columns are both 1?

Tags: r, grepl

I have two columns within a DF, "wet" and "cold", with values of 1 and 0 respectively, e.g:

```
Wet Cold
1     1
0     1
0     1
1     0
1     1
0     0
```

I would like to create a new column, wet&cold, where only if wet=1 *and* cold=1, then wet&cold=1. If any or both of them are 0 or not matching, then wet&cold=0.

I tried to work around with grepl, but without success.

Answer (score 5):

Base R solution

```
df$`wet&cold` <- df$Wet*df$Cold
df

  Wet Cold wet&cold
1   1    1        1
2   0    1        0
3   0    1        0
4   1    0        0
5   1    1        1
6   0    0        0
```

dplyr solution

```
df %>%
  mutate(`wet&cold`=Wet*Cold)

  Wet Cold wet&cold
1   1    1        1
2   0    1        0
3   0    1        0
4   1    0        0
5   1    1        1
6   0    0        0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option by checking I all row values have the value 1 for all the columns and convert the TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 with `as.integer` like this:

```r
df$wet_cold = as.integer(rowSums(df == 1) == ncol(df))
df
#>   Wet Cold wet_cold
#> 1   1    1        1
#> 2   0    1        0
#> 3   0    1        0
#> 4   1    0        0
#> 5   1    1        1
#> 6   0    0        0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Other solution works great with the clever multiplication. Here's perhaps a more general solution using `ifelse()`, which works well for this two case situation.

```
df <- data.frame(
    wet = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    cold = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)

df$wet_cold <- ifelse(df$wet == 1 & df$cold == 1, 1, 0)

df

#     df
#   wet cold wet_cold
# 1   1    1        1
# 2   0    1        0
# 3   0    1        0
# 4   1    0        0
# 5   1    1        1
# 6   0    0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&` to check if both are 1 and using + to convert `TRUE` or `FLASE` to `1` and `0`.

```
DF["wet&cold"] <- +(DF$wet & DF$cold)

#DF
#  wet cold wet&cold
#1   1    1        1
#2   0    1        0
#3   0    1        0
#4   1    0        0
#5   1    1        1
#6   0    0        0
```

Two more general approaches for more than two columns and also other conditions than `1` will be.

```
DF["wet&cold"] <- +(apply(DF==1, 1, all))

DF["wet&cold"] <- +(rowSums(DF != 1) == 0)
```

Data

```
DF <- data.frame(wet = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), cold = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))
```