# Combining two binary variables in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(Apple = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Banana = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

I want to create a binary variable that signifies if either Apple and/or Banana is 1.

- If both Apple and Banana are 0, then the value in the new variable should be 0.
- If Apple is 1 but Banana is 0 (and vice versa), then the value in the new variable should be 1.
- If Apple AND Banana is 1, then the value in the new variable should be 1.

This should be the output:

```
 dput(test)
structure(list(Apple = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Banana = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Apple_or_Banana = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Deja vu.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75162896/how-can-i-create-a-new-column-with-values-1-0-where-the-value-in-the-new-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test$Apple_or_Banana = as.numeric(test$Apple | test$Banana)
```

Gives the result that you are after, I think.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
test$Apple_or_Banana <- ifelse(rowSums(test) > 0, 1, 0)
```

Result:

```
  Apple Banana Apple_or_Banana
1     0      1               1
2     1      1               1
3     1      0               1
4     0      0               0
5     1      0               1
```

Comment: A similar variant might be `test$Apple_or_Banana <- +(rowSums(test) > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

A variant general approaches for more than two columns and also other conditions than 1 will be.

```
test$Apple_or_Banana <- +(apply(test==1, 1, any))

#test
#  Apple Banana Apple_or_Banana
#1     0      1               1
#2     1      1               1
#3     1      0               1
#4     0      0               0
#5     1      0               1
```